# Remove cookie from request and response headers apollo client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client, next.js13

I have the following mutation in nextJS apollo client

```
 const [mutateCV] = useMutation(MUTATION_SET_CV, { errorPolicy: 'none' });

    const handleCookie = async (request) => {
        await mutateCV({
            variables: {
                request,
            },
            context: {
                headers: {
                    authorization: '',
                },
            },
        });
    };
```

We have some cookies set by server as part of every request. I have to remove cookies in request headers. We send authorization as '' in headers but how can we remove specific cookies in request headers.

Comment: Do those cookies have `httpOnly` attribute? If so, there is nothirng to do by JavaScript. I'm also very curious why you want to remove cookies set by the server.